# distributing definitions in an .m file and memory

Tags: memory

I am dealing with a huge table stored in an .m file of size 4 GBs. Somehow when I call the table in .nb file it seems the memory increases not by 4 GBs but more than 10GBs (roughly checking from task manger). So my questions are
1) Does mathematica automatically distribute the content of an .m file to all the kernels?
2) If it distributes the definitions in an .m file to, say, 4 kernels, does it take 4 times more memory? 
3) If that's not the case what would be the reason behind that difference in the size of the file and the memory that the content takes?

Comment: It may help to give a sample of the data from the `.m` file.

Comment: Parallel kernels will not share variables unless explicitly stated, so if you distribute definitions they will be duplicateed. But if you do not use any parallel functionality (not clear from your question), that should not be a problem. Without the relevant code there is no way to answer properly.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question I think. But if the table you are storing is numerical, you can save it as a binary file - I use NetCDF *.nc usually, but if it's a regular array you can use the Matlab *.mat file format.  Doing this has the benefits of much smaller file size, smaller memory in reading the file, and much faster reading it in.

Comment: The data stored in .m file is 4th covariant derivative of a rank two tensor. It is a table of the form X[[aa,bb,cc,dd,ee,ff]] entries of which contains 10 different spacetime dependent functions and their derivatives up to order 4. A sample term in one entry is, say, D[D11[r,theta,phi,t],r]*r^2*Sin[theta]*D[A[r,theta,phi,t],t].... I hope this helps clarifying Mr Wizard. I am using paralleltable Yves Klett, but if it creates a memory problem I will stop using it. Jason would the sample above count as numerical? I am a first year user in mathematica and not familiar with many concepts. Thanks.